# Is Air Travel Supported on this API?

Tags: air, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I would like to know if this API also allows for calculating flight routes. For example, if I request a route between Frankfurt and Singapore, will it provide me with the route by road or by air? I noticed that transportation modes such as train, tram, and subway are available, but not air travel, which is why I am asking. Thank you in advance for your response.

I have thousands of departure and arrival cities traveled by travelers, and I would like to find out how many kilometers they have covered. I am not familiar with coding, but I understand that this API can help me do that. I want to make sure that air travel routes are accurately taken into account, as they represent the majority of the trips.

Comment: I am talking about Google Maps API Distance Matrix

Answer (score -1):

You already answered your own question. No, it is not. Air Travel is not a supported mode.

You can check out their supported modes in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix) and as of today they are all earth bound, no planes.